# Reading csv file from url

Tags: java

I wanted to read csv file (stock data) from url but with a variable start and end date (as input), is there any way I can do that? I have done that with static dates, I have started but I couldn't continue.

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class StockData {

    public StockData(String symbol, GregorianCalendar start, GregorianCalendar end) {

        String url = "https://quotes.wsj.com/fx/AEDUSD/historical-prices/download?MOD_VIEW=page&num_rows=300&startDate=12/01/2017&endDate=12/26/2018";

        try {
            URL rowdata = new URL(url);
            URLConnection data = rowdata.openConnection();
            Scanner input = new Scanner(data.getInputStream());
            if (input.hasNext())
                input.nextLine();

            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = input.nextLine();
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String symbol = new String();
        GregorianCalendar start = new GregorianCalendar(2018, 12, 12);
        GregorianCalendar end = new GregorianCalendar(2018, 12, 18);
        StockData test = new StockData(symbol, start, end);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem any error? and this if statement is useless `if(input.hasNext())
              input.nextLine();`

Comment: No error, but i want use a variable date instead of static, look into my url, i have specify the date , what if i want to input any date from the keyboard as input variable

Comment: Use scanner object to read data from user, and url is a string, so startDate and endDate must be strings so that you can append them in url @Naziru

Comment: Thanks, i can do that, but the problem is to construct the url, so that it includes the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm representing the idea here so you can code that because those are very minimal changes

> First use `Scanner object that reads input from user

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String symbol = new String(); //no need this
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in):
    //read user input using scanner object
    String start = //user input
    String end = //user input
    StockData test = new StockData(symbol, start, end);
}
```

> In the `StockData` constructor (this called constructor not method) just append the `endDate` and `startDate` to url

```
public StockData(String symbol, String start, String end) {

    String url = "https://quotes.wsj.com/fx/AEDUSD/historical-prices/download?MOD_VIEW=page&num_rows=300&startDate="+start+"+&endDate="+end;

    try {
        URL rowdata = new URL(url);
        URLConnection data = rowdata.openConnection();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(data.getInputStream());
        if (input.hasNext()) // remove
            input.nextLine();  //remove

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: try this, if you need help SO is here

Comment: It really helped @Deadpool